# Finding a bug concerning looping through objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am new to JavaScript and am taking the codeacademy course on it. I've been stuck on one part now for a long time and i can't quite understand what my bug is.

I am supposed to loop through an object which itself contains objects and return a specific property of the inner objects. The exact code is

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "bill",
        lastName: "bill",
        number: 0319382,
        address: ["one chocloate","yea","sup"]
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "steve",
        lastName: "steve",
        number:41234134,
        address: ["one chocloate","yea","sup"]    
    }

}
```

I'm making a function that checks if a name matches any first names within friends and if true returns that person's details. My current function is

```
var search = function(name){
    for (var k in friends){
        if (k[firstName] === name){
            for(var i in k){
                console.log(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advice for any responses and keep in mind i'm a complete beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (var i in k)` just sets `i` to the property names, not the values. To get the corresponding values, you have to use `k[i]`:

```
for (var i in k) {
    console.log(i + ' is ' + k[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code -> [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3HgD/1/)

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "bill",
        lastName: "bill",
        number: 0319382,
        address: ["one chocloate","yea","sup"]
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "steve",
        lastName: "steve",
        number:41234134,
        address: ["one chocloate","yea","sup"]    
    }

}

var search = function(name){
    for (var k in friends){
        var friend = friends[k]; //getting the index
        if (friend.firstName === name){
            //checking if the first name is equal to the passed one
            for(var i in friend){
                console.log(friend[i]); //getting the properties of the matched object                
               }
        }
    }
}

search('steve');
```